# Field axiom statement

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Mathematical_Analysis_(Zakon)/02%3A_Real_Numbers_and_Fields/2.01%3A_Axioms_and_Basic_Definitions

It's not obvious to me that the statement about the existance of a unique neutral element for multiplication couldn't be written with ∃!, and would be:   ∃!1 ∈ E, ∀x ∈ E : x · 1 = x , 1 ≠ 0.

Comment: It's weird that they write $\exists!$ for $0$ but not for $1$.  In both cases, you can prove the uniqueness from the other field axioms (proof sketch: if you have two neutral elements, try adding/multiplying them together), so the axioms don't have to *say* that they're unique.  But since they put it in the words, I'd expect them to put it in the symbols; and I'd certainly expect them to do both of them the same way.

Comment: By the way, you'll usually get more answers if you put quotations in text rather than using an image.  (In this case, you could almost just cut and paste, although you'd need some light editing to change ‘E1’ to ‘E¹’ and add some spacing for legibility.  It'd be even better, but more work, to use LaTeX.)

Answer (score 1):

It absolutely could be written like that, but it need not be written like that, because under the looser definition given uniqueness can be proved! In fact, the same is true of the additive neutral element $0$, and of the identities of groups in general. (For a field $F$, $F$ is a group under addition, and its nonzero elements are a group under multiplication.)

The underlying reason is a sort of desire for minimalism in mathematical definitions, especially where trivialities get eliminated: it means that there are fewer things to prove, and you only work with the essentials of what *really* needs to be proven.

To prove that the identity $e$ of a group $G$ under an operation $\ast$ is unique, one may suppose it has two distinct identities instead, $e,e'$. But then
$$
e = e \ast e' = e'
$$
from the defining properties, ensuring they are actually equal, and hence the identity is unique.

In the language of fields, then, if there were two zero elements, $0$ and $0'$, we could have
$$
0 = 0+0' = 0'
$$
by definition; or, if there were two multiplicative identities, $1$ and $1'$, we could have
$$
1 = 1 \cdot 1' = 1'
$$
(The left equality follows from the fact that $1'$ or $0'$ are an identity, and the right equality follows from the fact that $1$ or $0$ are an identity.) Either way, the identities are unique.

So, yes, you may write these with the "$\exists !$" phrasing if you wish; the uniqueness follows even if you don't assume uniqueness.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know how we can prove the uniqueness of the neutral elements, even without being explicitly stated in the axiom with an unique existential quantifier (∃!). I was really not sure why would they decide to not make it consistent, when it's clearly stated above that they are unique. Furthermore, the same thing could be said for the additive and multiplicative inverses, that we can prove their uniqueness without being explicitly stated in the axiom, but in those cases ∃! is used, so I was not sure if there was a particular reason for that being different.

Comment: I can't imagine why they would be inconsistent myself - the inconsistency, frankly, would annoy the hell out of me too. But the motivation as to why could only be answered by the author of the source material. One also has to wonder if it's an unintentional typo.